# In extjs how to globally handle errors

Tags: error-handling, extjs4

I am working in Extjs 4.1. I want to know is there anything available that can globally handle errors all over the entire application and how to implement such error handling in extjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of errors you are trying to handle globally. If you want to handle ajax errors globally yes you can do it like below

```
 Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options) {
        if(response.timedout){
            // handle time out
        }
        else if (response.status != 404) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If my answer helped you it will be great if you can mark my answer helpful :)